# appendix in two column paper

Tags: graphics

I want to create appendix in my paper to figure  and   table but  i got this result  as shown below.  The code that I use is:

```
\appendix
\appendix[Table index ]
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{classification of the Arab world's economies in 2014}
    \label{classification of the Arab world's economies in 2014}
    \begin{tabular}{IIIIIII}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth, height=6cm]
            {classificationOftheAraWorld'seconomiesIn2014.PNG}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\appendix
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello!  I took the liberty to edit your question, in order to format the code and to tidy it up a bit; but I was not able to understand what you are trying to achieve.  The code you posted makes no reasonable sense, and doesn’t produce the captions you are showing, so please check it yourself and clarify both the code and your question.

Comment: You should always provide a Minimum Working Example so we can reproduce your results and then figureout how to get to the answer.
You can read more about MWE here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with appendix at all.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide a working MWE I created one, which I guess is what you could be looking for. A very basic twopage article with figures and tables. Appendix is just a matter of adding the macros here.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure C}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 
 Random & Text \\ 
\hline 
 Any & Text \\ 
 \hline
 Any & Text \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 2}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 
 Random & Text \\ 
\hline 
 Any & Text \\ 
 \hline
 Any & Text \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 3}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 
 Random & Text \\ 
\hline 
 Any & Text \\ 
 \hline
 Any & Text \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 4}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 
 Random & Text \\ 
\hline 
 Any & Text \\ 
 \hline
 Any & Text \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]